# How to process energy (kWh) meter reading data of half-hour interval

Tags: power, energy, conversion

If I am to process time series of energy data (point estimate every half-hour interval), and fit it into the following formula for dimension reduction:

[Haben's paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOG5L.png)

I was advised to use power, not energy. Yet power is the rate at which the energy is formed. I still don't see how other than to use the values as it is. If I convert it into hourly value, it would remain the same. Must I divide by 2 to indicate that they are half-hour interval values? Then isnt it the same not applying? Since you would be normalizing with the entire year's data.

Aside from the energy/power concepts, (or maybe relevant) I actually was a bit confused how to process it to sample the time period from 6.30 am to 10.30 am for instance. If it is a point estimate, how can it be in unit of kWh?

Should perceive that the reading at 6.30 am is the electricity consumed from 6 - 6.30 am or now that I think if it is 5.30 - 6.30 am...

May I ask for clarification from anyone with solid experience in this matter? Thanks

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: no this is for my research..and for some reason i am applying clustering/coalition techniques on smart grid network without strong basics in understanding of power/energy.

Comment: "Haben's paper" - is this it? http://centaur.reading.ac.uk/47589/1/ClusteringPaper_v7%20-%20deformatted.pdf

Comment: @BruceAbbott They reference just one article on the use of PCA; a powerful tool and even more so when intelligently applied (for example, to reduce to important dimensions.) The paper's summary, so far as I can tell, discounts without comment anything that may have arrived from that reference. Now I'm curious to read their first referenced paper.

Comment: Uhm.. Can anyone answer my question? I know abt PCA but im sure the author used other dimension reduction method for its advantage.. I contacted him and was advised to use Power not Energy

Comment: Usually an energy meter displays the total amount of energy that's gone through the meter since it was manufactured, doesn't it?

Comment: In that case should I delete from all the readings the first reading registered? that would initialize all values.

Comment: Power is the derivative wrt time of energy. So if you have actual kWh meter readings every half hour, subtract the previous reading (kWh/half-hour) and double it (kWh/hour = kW). That's the average power over the last half hour, there's no way to get the peak power.

Comment: While your approach sounds convincing too.. there could be many instances when the kWh reading is lower than the previous 30-min interval. It doesn't make sense to have negative power does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather the purpose of statistical analysis here is to define the rate of peak Power demand during daily and seasonal diurnal loads, so kWh would not apply as the duration of Peak power for different times of the day or week or weekend.

These peak durations of interest will be much less than a hour yet the grid must be maintained dynamically ( impedance of net sources) to supply this peak power on demand and stay within specified voltage tolerances.

> If the meter reports kWh in 30 minute intervals then you use the average energy per reading  kWh x2 = P per 30 minute reading.

Comment: not sure where you read 'peak power demand'. From what I gather, the meter readings are point estimate per each 30 mins, data explained [here](http://www.ucd.ie/issda/data/commissionforenergyregulationcer/) without much details. or am I missing background that these are in fact peak power demands?

Comment: At any rate I get that the correct conversion would be multiplication of 2 but still.. why would I need to do that to normalize if I apply that to all the time series data and then divide?

Comment: This was a study done by Marhematicians, not the EE perspective that I gave.

Comment: yes but the purpose is to correctly understand the nature of the data and to expand on previous researches..if there is fallacy in interpretation then I shall improve on it. So in your opinion, the meter data represent peak power during the 30-min interval?

Comment: RMS power is standard but peak rms power loading even for a second is important data to a power study

Comment: Generally line voltage regulation specs are 5% for generation and transmission and 5% for distribution with impedances varying from 8 to 12 % implying load regulation on voltage with peak power changes. Although dynamic tap changers and adjustable generators are needed to support this, the surplus capacity must be planned to prevent brown outs and capacity must be carefully regulated so spurious peak powers are not detected as faults and can be supplied as very little of the energy is stored in distribution. So the statistics follow Bayon and Gaussion or other distributions.

Comment: sp.. Bayesian and Gaussian

Comment: Yup i got the last terms..but so, in sum u r saying that the meter readings are peak energy values of 30min interval and it is safe to estimate the power during that interval as double the point estimate?

Comment: Yes 1 kWh /0.5h= 2kW rms average. but digital meters can store more data than average, how they are reported is anyone's guess.